# How to make a Grid of items in which the Widgets are as close to each other as possible?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I am trying to clone the Google Keep mobile app for learning purposes and I can't make the notes appear as they do on the original app.

What I am currently using is a GridView.count with crossAxisCount set to 2 in order to simulate the "2 columns" effect. This is the code:

```dart
List<Widget> widgetList = new List<Widget>();
List<String> _names = [ /*This contains the text of each Card in a string*/ ];
Color backgroundCol = new Color.fromRGBO(230, 230, 230, 1.0);

void _makeCards() {

  widgetList = [];

  for (int i = 0; i < _names.length; i++) {
    Column myWidget = new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Flexible(
          fit: FlexFit.loose,
          child: new Card(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: new Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: new Text(_names[i], style: new TextStyle(fontFamily: 'RobotoSlab')),
            )
          )
        )
      ],
    );

    widgetList.add(myWidget);
  }
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  _makeCards();

  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text('Notes', style: new TextStyle(fontFamily: 'RobotoSlab')),
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      actions: <Widget>[new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: _onAdd)],
      ),
    drawer: new Drawer(),
    body: new Container(
      color: backgroundCol,
      child: new GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: widgetList,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Here are 2 screenshots, 1 with the wanted result and 1 with what I have tried.

[Wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYp5G.png)

[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsytZ.png)

Comment: What you are looking for is called masonry layout take a look at this library: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Unfortunately, I cannot accept it as an answer as it is a comment.